# Can I use PHP for mobile app development to send HTML form to email

Tags: php, html, cordova, email, cross-platform

I'm looking into creating an html app with Cordova. 
Now I know how to create a form for a website and using PHP to mail the form but my concern is, Would I be able to use PHP with my app to mail the form to an email? is there an article I can read that is relevant to my current situation? or maybe if you can refer me to another coding language I can use to substitute PHP if I cant use PHP to mail the form I hope I can use stack overflow to ask the question, Thanks!.

Comment: [php mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)?

Comment: I never saw people using php in android but html can be used. Mail functionality can be achieved using java.

Comment: thank you for the respond, but i'm looking into making my app cross-platform not just for android @RajendranNadar

Comment: @CD001 thank you for directing me to the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer is yes, I think you're confusing PHP (Backend language that runs at the server side) with Cordova( Hybrid-platform, client-side), Cordova by itself won't send the email with the form. unless you want cordova to work as mailer, here there is a plugin that let you send e-mail without backend https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer, using some of your accounts.

from Plugin documentation:

> The Email service is only available on devices which have configured an email account...

PHP let you to send the email from the server but for PHP render a HTML page in your Cordova Application must be through a WebView pointing to the url. by the other hand you can make the form in your Cordova Application with sources in your client-side and connect it through service. Make an request from your app with the data and receive it with PHP and make your business.

Comment: do you think i can use a cordova plugin to act as a mailer? and thank you for the answer!

Comment: @twinaholic it depends what you want, if you want to have control of data sent by your app, you will need the server, but if you want as a feature of your app without go out of it. the plugin would be a good option.

Comment: okay so if i want the user to submit the form straight from the app without going out of it i would have to use the plugin, Correct?

Comment: Perfect, Thank you so much for the Help!

Comment: How would I use the plugin with my app ? or maybe instead would you know a tutorial I could watch would be helpful, Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150867/discussion-between-jose-rojas-and-twinaholic).